# What does the grave accent sign (`) mean in R?

Tags: r, quantmod

Recently I encountered the following code that gives error:

```
> library(quantmod)
> getSymbols("000001.SS")
> names(000001.SS)
Error: unexpected symbol in "names(000001.SS"
> names("000001.SS")
NULL
```

while:

```
> names(`000001.SS`)
[1] "000001.SS.Open"     "000001.SS.High"     "000001.SS.Low"     
[4] "000001.SS.Close"    "000001.SS.Volume"   "000001.SS.Adjusted"
```

gives the desired result. I didn' t remember reading about it in tutorial or documentation. So how should the sign ` be used in R? Further clarification on using all these quoting signs or without them is better.

Comment: read `?make.names` and `?"'"` run `make.names('000001.SS')`. Backticks (\`) allow you to use normally invalid r variable names; look at the difference between rownames<-, 'rownames<-', and \`rownames<-\`

Comment: Have you looked at the `?Quotes` help page? It's there to provide clarification on all these quoting signs.